# One hot encoding in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am really new to coding, right now I am trying to turn my label to one hot encoding. I have already done transferring the np.array to tensor as shown below

```html
tensor([4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.,
        3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2.], dtype=torch.float64)
```

```html
and I am using code to do one hot encoding 

aaa = F.one_hot(torch_qyh, num_classes=5)
```

However, there is an error showing "RuntimeError: one_hot is only applicable to index tensor." Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to convert it in `long` type. Can't do it with float. `F.one_hot` only takes LongTensor.

```
F.one_hot(t.long())
```